# JavaScript RegEx - Match quoted string - Possibly unexpected result?

Tags: javascript, regex, browser

Why does this:

```
console.log(/^(['"])(?:(?:\\[^])|[^\\])*\1/.test('"\"'))
```

result in true? Is this expected behavior or a bug? If it's expected, how to achieve intended behavior, which is to result in false as the last closing quote in the example shouldn't be matched as it's escaped? Maybe I made a mistake in writing the RegEx, in which case, I hope someone can kindly point out the error to me...

For the uninitiated, the above regular expression in JavaScript is intended to match only a complete (meaning, the matched portion should be a complete quoted string, NOT that the whole input string should be a complete quoted string.) single or double quoted string that may or not contain backslash escaped special characters. Nested levels of escaped strings may be present. Also, for simplicity, and as per requirement, the match starts from the beginning of the input string, as otherwise, a match may be possible, incorrectly, starting from an already escaped quote.

Tested in Firefox 82.0.2 and Edge 86.0.622.63

Comment: Well, it works also on [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/8EUwwC/1)  My guess would be that \ characters mess something, as you have plenty of them :P

Answer (score 0):

Ah, never mind! I figured out that the problem is not in the RegEx, but in the way I crafted the input string. The way I've written it, the outer string interprets the escape instead of the backslash acting as an escape for the inner string! The correct way to write it is to escape the backslash, so the above code should be rewritten as:

```
console.log(/^(['"])(?:(?:\\[^])|[^\\])*\1/.test('"\\"'))
```

So, the result is as expected after all, and not a bug!